# Comparing two Oracle schema, other users

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been tasked with comparing two oracle schema with a large number of tables to find the structural differences in the schema. Up until know I have used the DB Diff tool in Oracle SQL Developer, and it has worked very well. The issue is that now I need to compare tables in a user that I cannot log into , but I can see it through the other users section in SQL developer. The issue is that whenever I try to use the diff tool to compare those objects to the other schema it does not work. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? It would save me a very large amount of work. I have some basic SQL knowledge if that is whats needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have been GRANTed permissions in that other schema, issue an

```
alter session set current_schema = OTHER_SCHEMA_NO_QUOTES_REQUIRED;
```

the run whatever tool.

Otherwise, it's `select * from all_tables where owner = OTHER_USER;`, 'select * from all_indexes where ...` etc.

Comment: I tried doing an alter session, but while it appeared successful, the DB diff yielded the same results, I guess I will just have just do a bunch of where owner = queries and manually diff the results. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just reviving this question with a correct answer.

If you can get your DBA to grant you proxy through you can do the following without knowing the password of the end schema:

```
ALTER USER {use you do not have pw to - lets call it ENDSCHEMA} GRANT CONNECT THROUGH {user you have pw for - lets call it YOURSCHEMA};
```

Then you create a connection in SQL Developer where:

```
username: YOURSCHEMA[ENDSCHEMA] 
password: YOURSCHEMA password
```

Then you can proceed and do a Database Diff on both schemas and never knowing the password for ENDSCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST You have to launch

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SCHEMA;
```

*BUT ALSO IN THE FIRST SCREEN OF DIFFERENCES TOOL YOU HAVE TO CHOOSE FOR DDL COMPARISON OPTIONS - SCHEMA - **"MANAGE"** (NOT CONSOLIDATE)*

(I have Sql Developer with italian interface, so I translated the options, the names could be a little different)

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Easily compare every things in two or more schemas using toad for oracle as in this pics

Step 1:
[image: From Toad Menu Database => Compare => Schemas]

Step 2: compare window will appear to add schemas you want to compare (by default connected schema will be the one above) then click next,
[image]

Step 3: select objects you want to compare in both schemas then run

[image]